# How to overwrite list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, overwrite

I wrote some code on how to overwrite a list and luckily got it to work but don't quite understand how it works. If I try to understand my own code, the length of the list numbs is 5 and when combined with the range method, I am asking my loop to loop 5 times, right?

The 2nd part of my question has to do with the numbs[w]. Is numbs[w] referencing an element in the list? So far I've learned numbs_list[1] references position 1 in the numbs_list but I'm not sure how the numbs[w] works on the left-hand side and right-hand side of the equation.

This is my first post on here so thank you for your help!

```
numbs = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]

for w in range(len(numbs)):
    numbs[w] = numbs[w] + 5

print(numbs)
```

The actual output is `[10, 15, 20, 25, 30]` which is what I wanted.

Comment: What exactly do you expect ?

Comment: `numbs[w]` refers each element of list by index `w`, and you add 5 to each element, so you get `[10, 15, 20, 25, 30]`

Comment: Read this blog to get a better understanding around this range :
https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/range/

Answer (score 0):

```
for w in range(len(numbs)):

  numbs[w] = numbs[w] + 5

  print(numbs)
```

Here,
len(numbs)=5, so range() returns sequence of numbers (0 to 4) [range() [documentaion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) with examples ]

numbs[0] refers to first element of the list (i.e. 5)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there is such thing as precedence meaning some parts of the code are evaluated before others. When you have an assignment operator (=), the right side is always evaluated before the assignment takes place.

So,

```
numbs[w] = numbs[w] + 5
```

is evaluated as such

```
# w gets the value from the for loop i.e. 0-4
numbs[0] + 5 # numbs[0] is 5, so this evaluates to 10
numbs[0] = 10 # the assignment takes place after the right side is evaluated
```

That's how your list ends up having each element incremented by 5

Also note, that numbs[w] = numbs[w] + 5 can be written as numbs[w] += 5

Answer (score 0):

As for your first question, yes you are asking it to loop for 5 times.
But here is how range works:
range(n) creates a sequence of numbers from 0 to n-1 and not 1 to n.
Hence,

```
for w in range(len(numbs)):
```

iterates the value of w from 0 to 4 i.e (5-1)

Now, for your second question:

Yes, your code is referencing the elements of numbs.
Lists are zero indexed , i.e the elements are indexed from 0 through n-1. Hence whenever
numbs[w] is used,  the element of numbs at index w is accessed.

For eg. numbs[0] = 5, numbs[1] = 10 and so on

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you break your problem down into small pieces and not try to use several functions you don't understand at the same time.  Use your print statements to figure this one out.

```
numbs = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]

#see what value you get from range(len(numbs))
print('range(len(numbs)) = ', range(len(numbs)))

for w in range(len(numbs)):
    #what is the value of w?
    print('w = ', w)

    #print numbs[w] before it is changed
    print('numbs[w] = ', numbs[w])

    numbs[w] = numbs[w] + 5

    #print numbs[w] after it is changed
    print('numbs[w] = ', numbs[w])

    #add another print to separate the loops
    print()

#print numbs after the for each loop has ran
print('new numbs = ', numbs)
```

Then you can put them all together and figure out what's going on.